# Driving a D3 chart with and without d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, transition, interpolation

I have a piece of code that creates a donut (i.e., d3.layout.pie()).

I used to load JSON data in the following way

```
d3.json(jsonFilePath,
    function(json) {
             //logic
             ....
            })
```

My visualizations are interactive (i.e., the donut variates in size, both innerRadius and "d" attribute). So I correctly implemented the three cases, enter, remove and update and the attrTween function to transition the "d" attribute.

It worked until now. I decided to implement some sort of caching mechanism (i.e., I've a variable that holds the data so that data are pre-fetched once and re-used if needed again). I tested the behavior of my cache and it's working. **Here's a snippet...**

```
if(cache[name] == undefined) {
    console.log('Loading data and create viz');

    // Loading all the JSONs for this name
    var remaining = revs.length; 
    // revs is an array w/ json file names to load (elements in the form r1, r4 etc.)

    var current = {};

    for (var i in revs) {
        d3.json(revs[i] + ".json" , function(json) {

            current["r"+json.revision] = json;

            if (!--remaining) {
                // Data loaded, here, hence setting cache
                cache[appName] = current;
                createViz(rev);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

I come to the point. I replaced the way I used to load data with a simple access  of my cache data containing the loaded JSON string, so now instead of the above code block I've something that looks like

```
var currentCache = cache[someName];
var json = currentCache[revisionName];
```

When I inspect the json variable the json is correcty loaded and looks fine. The point is that now the transition is no longer working and I got lot of messages such as

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M2.1431318985078682e-14,-350A350,350 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA230.68565589945686,230.68565589945686 0 1,0 1.412542250532388e-14,-230.68565589945686Z"
```

I already faced this messages  before, but now the thing is that I dunno why this is happening. The code is unchanged, instead of using d3.json() I'm using the json string from a variable. Any suggestion?

I attach part of the code for reference...

```
// An array of objects such as {"name" : myObject, "calls" : 23}
var calls = json.children;

var donut = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.calls; })
    .sort(null)

var arcs = d3.select("#vizGroup")
    .selectAll(".callSlice")
    .data(donut(calls));

//update
arcs
    .data(donut(calls))
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return somecolor(d.data.name); } )


//enter
arcs.enter()
    .append("svg:path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return somecolor(d.data.name); } )
    .attr("stroke", "#EEF")
    .attr('class', 'callSlice')
    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)


//remove
arcs.exit().remove();

function arcTween(a) {
    a.innerRadius = myScale(myVariable);

    var i = d3.interpolate({
        startAngle: this._current.startAngle, 
        endAngle: this._current.endAngle,
        innerRadius: this._current.innerRadius}, a);

    this._current = i(0);

    return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your snippet refers to an undefined variable `rev`. Also, don't use a [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) with an array. I'm going to assume you meant something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, n = revs.length; i < n; ++i) {
  d3.json(revs[i] + ".json", function(json) {
    var rev = revs[i];
    /* do something with rev here */
  }); 
}
```

Or equivalently, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, n = revs.length; i < n; ++i) {
  var rev = revs[i];
  d3.json(revs[i] + ".json", function(json) {
    /* do something with rev here */
  }); 
}
```

Neither of these will work as expected because the d3.json callback is asynchronous, and closures don't capture the value of `rev` (or for that matter `i`) in the current iteration of the for loop: they capture a *reference*, not a *value*, and so when the callback is invoked at a later point, all your callbacks will see the value in the *last* iteration of the for loop (`revs.length`), not the value when each d3.json is called.

You can fix this by capturing the value with a closure. For example:

```
for (var i = 0, n = revs.length; i < n; ++i) {
  fetch(revs[i]);
}

function fetch(rev) {
  d3.json(rev + ".json", function(json) {
    /* do something with rev here */
  }); 
}
```

This works because each unique value of `rev` is captured by the function `fetch`. For more on closures, see:

- http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: Hi Mike. I'll try your suggestion now. The thing is that I'm already using the code elsewhere and works perfectly. Don't u see any error in my attrTween stuff or data binding up there?

Comment: Btw rev is the selected value of a select box (i.e., var rev = revSelector.options[revIndex].value;) that has the form "r34" for example.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't solve the issue. I'm sure it has something to do with the transition.

Comment: Moreover, I've another element in the viz that is updating correctly, always using the values from the cached JSON. It's a circle pack layout visualizing other pieces of info taken from the cached JSON. The error is somewhere in the transition of the donut but I could not manage to spot it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you've included the code that is at fault, which I suspect is your JSON caching code. My guess is that you're still fetching JSON asynchronously, but you're trying to use it right away. `d3.json()` takes a callback function that isn't invoked until the data is actually loaded - I'm not seeing any similar structure in your current code, so unless you're loading the JSON inline, rather than from a remote file, that's likely to be the issue.

Checking the console manually won't help in this case, because by the time you check the console, the data *has* been loaded - it's when your code is actually running that you have problems.

Comment: I added the code used to load data. I'm 99% sure the code does what's supposed to do.

Comment: So that last code snippet is within `createVis()`? Can you `console.log(calls)` just before you use it?

Comment: Also of note in your cache: your cache check is `cache[name]` but you're setting `cache[appName]`. I can't tell from your code whether that's a typo or intentional.

Comment: I just changed the code on the fly to put it here. The actual code has no typo and runs :)